# Iterator<Strings> isnt working for HashTable Test

Tags: java, iterator, hashtable

The `Iterator<String> elements()` method I wrote for my hash table is not passing one of the tests I have been given.  What's wrong with this?

```
public Iterator<String> elements(){
    Iterator<String> it = new Iterator<String>(){

        private int i = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i < hashTable.length && hashTable[i] != null;  //if i set this to always return true i get a null.pointer.exception.
                                                                  // then an error on line 115 which is the line for next().
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            i++;
            return hashTable[i].getKey();
        }

    };
    return it;
}
```

Here is the test:

```
    /** Test 8: Get iterator over all keys 
 * @throws MapException */
private static boolean test8() throws MapException {

    boolean result = true;
    String s;
    StringHashCode sHC = new StringHashCode();
    float maxLF = (float) 0.5;
    HashTableMap h = new HashTableMap(sHC,maxLF);
    try
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) 
        {
            s = (new Integer(k)).toString();           
            h.insert("R"+s+"C"+s);
        }

        for (int k = 10; k < 30; k++) 
        {
            s = (new Integer(k)).toString();
            h.remove("R"+s+"C"+s);
        }
    }
    catch(MapException e)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    Iterator<String> it = h.elements();
    int count = 0;

    while (it.hasNext()){
        count++;
        it.next();
    }
    if ( h.numberOfElements() != 80) {
        result = false;           
    }
    if ( count != 80) {
        result = false;           // if i comment out this line the test passes so i am assuming the iterator is the problem.                    
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am sure my code for the `Iterator<String> elements()` method is correct but I am probably missing a simple error because I have been looking at it so long.

Comment: *"I'm sure my code is correct, but I am probably missing a simple error"*  I'm guessing that actually you're not sure, then...  Anyway, why do you think that `elements()` is at fault, and not, say, `remove()`?

Comment: The rest of the tests pass to test my remove() and insert() methods

Comment: I can add my remove() and insert() methods if you would like to see them?

Comment: Is there any null value in the table?

Comment: Also don't you need to increase i?

Comment: ive incremented i. But its still failing.

Comment: if i set hasNext() to always return true i get a NullPointerException at line 115 which is the line for next().

Comment: You should increase i after `hashTable[i].getKey()`